# How to create a reliable repeating task?

Tags: java, android, service, task, repeat

I'm really new to Android (and java) programming. I'm struggling to create a reliable repeating background task. It should run quite often, let's say in every 10sec, even if the phone is in sleep. I've tried already a lot of things, but without success.

As I learned, AlarmManager is not reliable under ~15min interval.
Tried with FireBase JobDispatcher also.

Now I'm using service and timertask with scheduleAtFixedRate in the background. Till now this is the best, but still unreliable.
In every run of the task I have to do a database read, do some notification if needed, and write some data to DB.

I'm using FULL_WAKE_LOCK also, but still have a lot of missing notifications, or sometimes I get 10-20 notification in the same time with the delay of few minutes.

What would be the right way to do this job and make it reliable?
(push is not possible at the moment from server side)

Comment: "It should run quite often, let's say in every 10sec, even if the phone is in sleep" -- modern Android specifically prevents this sort of behavior, because users get *very* angry when apps do this, due to battery drain. "What would be the right way to do this job and make it reliable?" -- given Doze mode, app standby, and the upcoming changes in Android P, there are no options for frequent reliable periodic work.

Comment: "because users get very angry when apps do this, due to battery drain" - Yes, I'm aware of this. But in that case it's more important to get the notifications in time.